# ffmpeg padding while leaving audio track unchanged

Tags: ffmpeg, padding, audiotrack

My cheap 16:9 TV is not able to play correctly a 1280x544 video (I see the 2.35:1 aspect ratio image vertically stretched to 16:9 aspect ratio, incomprehensibly the TV aspect ratio adjustment is disabled if source is USB), so I used `ffmpeg` (on Windows 10) to add two 88 pixels high horizontal black bars in order to get to a 1280x720 video with a 16:9 aspect ratio, using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i my_input_video.mkv -filter:v "pad=1280:720:0:88" my_output_video.mkv
```

My TV play the new video correctly, but it says that the audio is not supported, whereas in the original video it was.

How can I pad the original video leaving the audio track unchanged?

Comment: Please post info about initial and converted files. Use `ffmpeg -i video.mkv` for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i my_input_video.mkv -filter:v "pad=1280:720:0:88" -c:a copy my_output_video.mkv
```